# Django formsets... bound, request,... coding pattern?

Tags: django, django-forms, formsets

I am currently going through the base django documentation as I am trying to come up with some basic edit view class for an old project of mine. For this I have to work with formsets. I am confused at the pattern of calls used within this example for producing an edit view.

What is the exact reason why you have to instantiate the formset for the validation with the request.POST, and for errors you recreate the whole thing again with your initial instance... (Otherwise it won't show any data)

```
def manage_books(request, author_id):
    author = Author.objects.get(pk=author_id)
    BookInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Author, Book, fields=('title',))
    if request.method == "POST":
        formset = BookInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=author)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            # Do something. Should generally end with a redirect. For example:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(author.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        formset = BookInlineFormSet(instance=author)
    return render(request, 'manage_books.html', {'formset': formset})
```

Comment: I'm confused by your question. This code *doesn't* recreate the formset again for errors; if the formset is not valid, then execution falls through to the last line. The else is for displaying the formset initially so that you can enter data in it.

Comment: You are correct, now if I would add an else: formset = BookInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=author) it won't show all the data. I have this specific pattern in my own code, and images don't show up...

Comment: But why would you add that?

Comment: To show the data that the user previously typed in, and let them correct the data according to the error message.

Comment: But there is no need to add anything in order to do that, because the above code already does what you want.

Comment: The whole thing is confusing to me, as I think in the following way "Person does an error, show person what they did, tell where they were wrong",... but the another way would be "Person does an error, send unchanged error free previous data, tell person where an error is." Is that the general django rationale?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156162/discussion-between-claude-and-daniel-roseman).

Comment: No and I can't understand why you think that. "Show person what they did and tell where they were wrong" is **exactly** what your original code is doing.

Comment: I think I found my error. In my code I was sending out an empty formset in GET and awaiting the user to chose an instance from a dropdown. After choosing an instance they would pass their choice to me, but also the empty previous formset, which would empty my formsets... Thank you very much for taking your time! (I never posted my code, this code above was from the docs, and I was misreading it on top of doing a mistake in my own code)